# Does FusionAuth use a random salt for each password in Salted PBKDF2 HMAC SHA-256?

Tags: random, salt, fusionauth

I am trying to find if FusionAuth uses a random salt for hashing algorithm in **Salted PBKDF2 HMAC SHA-256**

Comment: If I look [at the doc](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/reference/password-hashes#salted-pbkdf2-hmac-sha-256) the user is supposed to supply the salt. I'd *recommend* a 16 byte secure random salt, but in the end it is up to you.

Comment: The link provided by @MaartenBodewes does have some pseudo code.  Thank you for referencing this! This code is provided to help end users understand if it can be used when migrating from a 3rd party system. In practice FusionAuth generates the salt at runtime, or it is provided on the Import API when import existing hashes from a 3rd party platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new salt is generated when the user is initially created, and each time the password is changed.

The salt is `32` bytes in length. The one exception to this is `bcrypt` which uses a `16` byte salt.

The only time the `salt` can be provided by the end user is on the [Import API](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/users#import-users).